# sending email to user

Tags: email

im new to sharepoint. im trying to make a state machine workflow with a function to send email notification to user and checker (basically to check the file uploaded). somehow im stuck when using send email tool in vs2010. i have found a possible solution by using something like this "createTask1.TaskProperties.SendEmailNotification = true;". will you be kind enough to give suggestion or simple to understand tutorial on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use the [SPUtility.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms411989.aspx), if you're developing the workflow yourself.

Example:

```
SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(), true, false, "mail@mail.com", "Hello, this is Steve mailing you");
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have a column for Person/People as type, you can do this: 
If you are using SharePoint Designer 2013, you can set the If condition first and for the THEN, click on the "Action" menu drop down and select "Send Email"

This is what I did:

Step 1: Select Action "Send Email"

Step 2: click to edit the 'users' and click on the book icon of "To" field
[image]

Step 3: Choose "Workflow Lookup for a User..." and click on ADD
[image]

Step 4 and 5: From the "Lookup for Person or Group" window, choose the correct source in the source "Field from source"; in my case, the column titled "Dept. Stakeholder" Step 5: Choose "Return field as" field as 'Display Name' and click ok
[image]

End result should look like this:
[image]

The above steps created the correct algorithm engine to select the respective user from the "Current Item" field. In testing phase, I switched users for an assignment multiple times in the Column value in the Document Library. As long as the primary parameters to trigger the workflow met, SP activated the workflow and send out the email.